# Dynamic css for lightning card

Tags: lightning, lightning-web-components

I am facing issue when i am try to set dynamic css for lightning card which are in iteration i tried by using record id can anyone help me

```
<template>
<template for:each={lstOppotunities} for:item="opp">
    <div key={opp.Id} >
<div  class="slds-box" data-id={opp.Id} onclick={handleClick1} >
    {opp.Name}
</div>
 <lightning-button variant="brand" label="class 2"
 title="Primary action" onclick={handleClick2} 
 class="slds-m-left_x-small" data-id={opp.Id}></lightning-button>
</div>
 </template>

 </template>
```

Controller:

```
import { LightningElement,track } from 'lwc';
import getOpportunities from 
'@salesforce/apex/OpportunityController.fetchOpportunities';

export default class DataIDD extends LightningElement {
@track lstOppotunities = [];
constructor(){
    super();

    getOpportunities({}).then(response => {
        this.lstOppotunities = response;
    }).catch(error => {
        console.log('Error: ' +error.body.message);
    });
}

handleClick1(event){

    const oppId = event.currentTarget.dataset.id;
    console.log(oppId);
    if(this.template.querySelector(`[data-id='${oppId}]`)){
        this.template.querySelector(`[data-id='${oppId}]`).className='class1';
    }        
}
handleClick2(event){
    const oppId = event.currentTarget.dataset.id;
   console.log(oppId);
    if(this.template.querySelector(`[data-id='${oppId}]`)){
        this.template.querySelector(`[data-id='${oppId}]`).className='class2';
    }
}
}
```

Css class:

```
.class1 {
    background-color: #e6e618;
 }.class2 {
    background-color: #df6e18;
 }
```

Comment: Try with this: if(this.template.querySelector('[data-id="' + oppId + '"]')){
        this.template.querySelector('[data-id="' + oppId + '"]').className='class2';
       console.log('hiii');
    }

Comment: Thank You Himanshu it was very helpful